# Passing property from parent to child component in react not working as expected (newbie)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following react component that works as expected.

Data is returned from the Api call to the `forecasts` variable and is displayed correctly as `contents`.

My `WeatherCard` is rendered with the props passed successfully.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import WeatherCard from './WeatherCard.jsx'
import './App.css';

function App() {
    const [forecasts, setForecasts] = useState();
    const headerTitle = "Sadisticus' Weather App";


    useEffect(() => {
        populateWeatherData();
    }, []);



    const contents = forecasts === undefined
        ? <p><em>Loading... Please refresh once the ASP.NET backend has started. See <a href="https://aka.ms/jspsintegrationreact">https://aka.ms/jspsintegrationreact</a> for more details.</em></p>
        : <table className="table table-striped" aria-labelledby="tabelLabel">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                    <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                    <th>Summary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {forecasts.map(forecast =>
                    <tr key={forecast.date}>
                        <td>{forecast.date}</td>
                        <td>{forecast.temperatureC}</td>
                        <td>{forecast.temperatureF}</td>
                        <td>{forecast.summary}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>;
    
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <section className='App-header'>
                    <h2 id="tabelLabel">{headerTitle}</h2>
                </section>
                <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
                {contents}
                <WeatherCard weather={{ Date: '1/12/2023', TemperatureC: '23' }} />
                <h2>Something</h2>
            </div>
        </>
    );
    
    async function populateWeatherData() {
        const response = await fetch('weatherforecast');
        const data = await response.json();
        setForecasts(data);
    }
}

export default App;

import './App.css';
import Avatar from './Avatar';
function Card({ children }) {
    return (
        <div className='card'>
            {children }
        </div>
    );
}
export default function WeatherCard({weather }) {
    return (
        <Card>
            <Avatar forecast={weather}/>
        </Card>    
    );
}

export default function Avatar({ forecast }) {
    return (
        <>
            <h2>{forecast.Date}</h2>
        <img    className='avatar'
                src='https://i.imgur.com/szV5sdG.jpg'
                alt="Image"
            />
            <p>{forecast.TemperatureC} (C)</p>
        </>
    );
}
```

this works as fine and the data is rendered as expected.

Now how do I use the variable `forecasts` to pass properties to the `WeatherCard` component?

ie:

```
<WeatherCard weather={forecasts[0]} />
```

Actually, when I try this I get a blank page...

Comment: Re: "when I try this I get a blank page": Have you checked your browser's web-developer console for error messages?

Comment: It sounds like you might be mixing up `forecast` and `forecasts`.

Comment: Typo - I am trying to access forecasts[0] but nothing happens. I know forecasts was populated in the `populateWeatherData` call because the table is rendered by `{contents}`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it similarly to your Avatar component. If you want to restructure it you can use the spread operator:

```
<WeatherCard weather={...forcasts} />
```

**OR**

if it's an array of data you will need to map it:

```
forcasts.map((forcast)=>(<WeatherCard weather={forcast} />))
```